# populate multi select with two tabels

Tags: mysql, angularjs

I have two databases , db1 stores cities and another db stores selected cities for particular user by storing index of city separated by comma.

I have one multi select control on my UI, that control I populate with values of db1 i.e. cities. now i want to select all cities which are selected for particular user which is in db2.

for example multi select populates with all the cities. now for logged user there is "4,5,11" stored in db2. 
by using this value i want to select city which have index in 4,5,11.

Comment: with 2 databases you mean 2 tables?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Do you only want to show the cities that have an index in db2 in the multi-select? is there more than one UI element? your description is a little confusing.

Comment: Yes. @banncee There is only one element i.e. multi select.